# How do i sign out of user using Youtube Data API via Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Currently having a bit of trouble looking for a solution to allow users to sign out of my app using the javascript library for the Youtube Data API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#upload_video

I'm implementing the upload video script and but I don't see a clear way of allowing the user to sign out. It seems like the gapi provided in that example doesn't have the auth2 object to do signouts via gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is to revoke the access token so that the users will be asked again to authorize it.

It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) that it is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it. Programmatic revocation is important in instances where a user unsubscribes or removes an application. In other words, part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.

I also found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kt6zpZJiHU) here that can show how to create logout button that destroy the access token and this video use JavaScript that you want

Hope it helps you.